# Asynctask and passing an arraylist to it giving me error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have simple program that gets JSON data from the Google Images API. It stores all the URLs in that JSON in an ArrayList. I created an AsyncTask to handle this. When I run the program, I am getting the following errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.bab.googleimagesapi.MainActivity$myTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:84)
            at com.example.bab.googleimagesapi.MainActivity$myTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

It says there is a `NullPointerException` at lines 58 and 84. 
This is my code for the Asynctask, I have commented lines 58 and 84 so you can find them.

```
    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String> > {  **//LINE 58**

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String imageUrl = "x";
            String query = editText.getText().toString();            //get users search query
            query = query.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/imagesv=1.0&q=" + query + "&userip=INSERT-USER-IP");
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.addRequestProperty("referer", "www.github.com");
                String line;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                    JSONObject sub = jsonObject.getJSONObject("responseData");
                    JSONArray results = sub.getJSONArray("results");
                    for(int x = 0; x < results.length(); x++) {
                        JSONObject jsonImage = results.getJSONObject(x);
                        imageUrl = jsonImage.getString("url");
                        urlList.add(imageUrl);        **//LINE 84**
                    }
                    return urlList;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // textResult = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //textResult = e.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list) {

            for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++){
                textView.append(list.get(x));
            }
        }
    }
```

I am new to using AsyncTask and Android in general, so I appreciate any help!

Comment: Where are you initializing your `urlList`?

Comment: Also, there is nothing wrong using `URLConnection` but I find it better to use Android's (Apache) HttpClient. More info at: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `urlList` before using it:

```
urlList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: i accidently declared and initialized it in my MainActivity class. Thanks very much..!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `urlList` inside your `myTask`

```
urlList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or declare it as final.

On a side note, I wouldn't recommend you to use `AsyncTask` on Android. Read more about it here:
http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/